# Can I request a moderator to re-activate my SO account that has been suspended because of mistake?

Tags: support, status-declined, account-suspension

I have been participating on Stack Overflow for the last 4 months. I found that it is the best Q&A site for beginners, and I received solutions to many of my problems there. So I started sharing my knowledge.

But 2 days ago, I made one mistake of copying one answer from Stack Overflow and posted it as my own answer. I didn't know that was a bad thing, and my account got suspended.

Now I would like to request that the moderators please kindly forgive me once. This kind of mistake will never happen again. How can I request that a moderator do this? I desperately want to come back to SO.

Comment: You were messaged regarding the suspension on both the site and via e-mail. You're saying you didn't receive _either_?

Comment: @TimPost, I got the message from the Moderator but didn't get any mail. I accept that i did the mistake and I am really sorry for that. Can't moderator give me another chance for improvement?

Comment: Sure, as soon as the suspension is over. You'll be more than welcome back :)

Comment: @Scorpion It is extremely rare, for any diamond moderator to reverse a suspension unless there is intervention by actual site management, or really, really extreme mitagating reasons. To be honest, without them revealing exactly why your were suspended in detail, even asking on meta will not help, as the community does not know the full extent of why you where suspended, unless the moderators themselves reveal the reason, which is extremely rare. As everyone has said, ride it out, spend the time learning how others use SO, and then start again when the suspension is automatically lifted.

Comment: @Diago, okkkkk...Thanks for your response....

Comment: @TimPost [status-declined]?

Comment: @Diago well.. it is a support request to unsuspend right now..

Comment: Why everybody downvote this question?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @TimPost, my SO account is suspended without any notification and no description of that. I answered good questions and asked some good questions too. in the current technology that I am working is really have good questions as to its new, I am not sure why it's blocked, people were accepting my answers but suddenly I cant answer and cant ask

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given that your user account page says

> This account is [temporarily suspended](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) for voting irregularities.

It's pretty safe to assume that you were **not** suspended for

> one mistake of copying one answer from the SO and posted it as answer

In general, we don't suspend people for a single infraction. As the link provided indicates, suspensions are levied for a *pattern* of abusive behavior with no attempt to rectify or modify that offensive behavior.

Specifically, "voting irregularities" suggests that you have a history of engaging in fraudulent activity and attempting to abuse the reputation system, either by using a sockpuppet account or repeatedly voting for friends' accounts.

But when your suspension ends on May 13th at 13:48, you are welcome to come back, assuming you modify your behavior in accordance with our rules and expectations:

> At the end of this timed suspension period, your reputation will be recalculated, and **your account will resume as normal**. We don’t hold grudges. The point of all this is to address the behavior. If the behavior improves, you are welcome back.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. So before May 13 my account will not get activated?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: What's with this "we" stuff? =P

Comment: @casper: I am a moderator on one of the SE 2.0 sites, just not on SO. I've suspended a couple of people, but not for voting irregularities. And "we" is much easier to understand and much friendlier than "they". Saying "they" also sounds like I'm trying to push the blame off on someone else, which is not the case, considering that I fully support the decision.

Comment: @CodyGray Respect the emoticon at the end of the comment. =)