# Asking in the dark. A better reputation scoring or tag needed for Novice users

Tags: feature-request, moderation, moderators, moderator-abilities

Although this question has been marked duplicate. This question: [Add the ability to ignore users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users?rq=1) is more the question I was asking. I'm not asking to be ignored.  I just don't want to bother the higher ups with my dumb questions.

Answers may very do to each individual SE policy.

I had a positive reputation when I posted this question and still got suspended. When I wrote this I thought I was OK to post as many questions I wanted and the worst would happen is a question suspension, but I got fully suspended. I easily got longer suspensions for very minor mistakes.

When I revise my poor quality questions it just get more down votes furthering other kinds of bans like the 6 month/indefinite question ban.

The rules are defined, but the most important rules not stated like how many votes can one person give to another? How many "questions received poorly" can be asked before a full suspension is applied? and others limits would have really helped me from stumbling into full year suspensions.

It would have been nice if I got something saying 1 more bad question or anything and your suspended.

**Why can't up grades be made to this system for one user to block/ingore another user if they are bored and/or annoyed by the questioner thus allowing lower lever users to answer it for them and giving everyone a chance to answer?**

Comment: There are rules here, there are very effective tools to detect misbehavior. Once detect you get warnings, bans or suspensions, that is all explained openly and transparently. You have taken the risk, now you pay the price for that behavior. It is not us who are at fault, right?

Comment: @rene there's always a chance (slim as it may be) that such things happens without malicious intent, see my answer.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't the place for this kind of question, since we don't have access to the data that would prove you right or wrong. Your only option is "contact us".

Comment: related: [Can I request a moderator to re-activate my SO account that has been suspended because of mistake?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125841/201151)

Comment: The correct procedure is to use "contact us" since we don't have any things to see any proof (unless the mod wants to disclose it in public), but be patient, please? "Contact us" is not a realtime customer support, and there are also many backlogs that need to be cleared. Edit: and it's December aka holiday season.

Comment: @Muze Did you get at least a mod warning before your next suspension term???

Comment: @peterh nothing what so ever.

Comment: Sorry, but don't your multiple previous suspensions count as warnings? It's up to you to comprehend the reasons for the suspensions, and not repeat them.

Comment: @DmitryBrant  A warning is a warning not a suspension. Many of us would like to get a kiss before we're Fsuspended.

Comment: Too strict......

Comment: To be quite frank, from what I can tell you've been given a quite substantial amount of guidance from the community.  You were given plenty of feedback on the issues with your posts; and plenty of feedback on why serial voting and low quality algorithms aren't shared.  See meta questions [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/148704/muze?tab=questions).  I honestly don't think this is an issue with the system, but an issue with your compatibility in the system.  Things like you mentioning making another sock puppet really suggest you haven't learned your lesson.

Comment: @Muze  Why don't *you* get with peterh and help build Physics Overflow, and finally leave Physics SE alone?

Comment: @Muze From what I strongly suspect happened, your suspension was for something you specifically asked about doing in a meta thread, and were warned by multiple users not to do it.  You just came back from a very long suspension, and immediately did something that should have been obvious not to do; along with trying to circumvent the suspension in the first place.  I'm not sure why I would want to help with a site for users like that, honestly...  You've gotten very long warnings already; why should new ones be shorter?

Comment: @Muze (my final comment in this thread.) There's nothing stopping you from "enjoying" it:  suspended users are still able to *read* all the content, so you can still learn whatever you like, by figuring out how to *search* for what you want to learn.  You're also free to go literally anywhere else on the internet, and learn from the breathtaking amount of resources that are out there.  There's nothing about Stack Exchange that makes it particularly unique for learning elementary physics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider what happened as if you have been brought in front of a judge and found guilty.

Three months are not short time, but not eternity either.

I am 100% sure the team spent some time before issuing the suspension to make sure it's valid, so trying to say otherwise won't serve any purpose.

All in all, your only option now is to wait until the suspension is over and make sure such thing won't happen again.

One thing is for sure, somehow your account had voting irregularities. If you were not cheating as you say, there are several other options:

1. People who know you upvoted your posts regularly from the same IP as yours, e.g. co-workers, or friends using shared computer.
2. Your account has been hacked and used to vote somebody else.

So tell everyone you know to not upvote all your posts, and change your password. Just to be sure.

Comment: Co-workers voting for each other generally doesn't result in a suspension, unless they keep doing it after being warned. And a three month suspension usually means that it isn't the first one, or a particularly egregious case.

Comment: @Mad well, I can't know that, and there's always the chance the OP missed the warnings, e.g. registering with false/inactive email.

Comment: Mod messages are also shown in your inbox as well as sent per mail, it's pretty hard to miss them.

Comment: @Mad I see. Well, I can't think of anything else - giving the OP here the most possible benefit of the doubt. From here on, it's what you suggested.

Comment: @MadScientist I didn't ever get any warning just before suspension. Every time I was suspended I was told after the fact and for very minor stuff